# Setup windows share on Ubuntu Server 10.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, filesystems

I was wondering if anyone could provide me, or give me a link to a easy to follow step by step guide to setting up a share on Ubuntu Server 10.10.

Requirements:

- Need to share the folder /var/www/ with full read + write privileges
- Don't want the user to have to enter a password to gain access when within the network
- Need users to be able to connect from Windows, Mac and Linux to the drive

I'm reasonably capable with the linux command line but just having no luck using samba for the above requirements.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Do you already have a Windows domain or other centralized authentication system?  How to answer your no-password requirement could be a lot different depending on what you have.

Comment: No centralized authentication system, all on a workgroup but no domain so logins are independent to each machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [should help](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html) you get it all configured and setup for a workgroup.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much! Why couldn't I stumble across that?! :)

Comment: Your welcome, sometimes the easiest things go right over our heads :D